# facebook graph api create wall post with uploaded picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following these steps to create a wall post with a picture using the FB Graph API:

1. Upload the picture into a specified folder (working OK)
   -> this returns an **id** and a **post_id**
2. Send a POST to *https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed* with the following parameters:

> access_token - my current access_token
>
> message - a simple message like "hello"
>
> object_id -the **post_id** obtained in step 1, after photo upload

The post message appears on the wall, but there is no photo:

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/1369/screenshot6ev.png

What am I doing wrong?

I mention that i don't want to attach a link to the photo. I want the image to appear without any hiperlink, like the ones that are manually uploaded when creating a new post.

Comment: You can only give the `picture` parameter for a post when you also use `link`, otherwise it'll be ignored. If you want to post a photo directly, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Ok, but how can I mimic the same behaviour as when I click the "What's on your mind?" box, type something, then click Photo -> Upload, etc.? This is what I want to do..

Comment: And that’s why I linked the relevant parts of the documentation!

Comment: Ok. The first link you gave me ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) is about posting a photo on the user's wall. I don't want this. I need to create a POST on the wall containing a picture. A photo upload notification is not a post. The second link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) describes the Photo object from the Graph API.

Comment: My problem is related to the Feed, not the Photo, as I already succeeded uploading a photo. I've done some research and it seems that back in 2011 there was an *object_reference* parameter in the Feed POST request that allowed you to attach a photo. However, that field doesn't exist anymore. It should have been replaced by *object_id*.. which I already tried but doesn't quite work. Maybe it's a bug..

Comment: The `object_id` is a field you get when _reading_ a post from the API – you can not set it while creating a post. Your _only_ way to get a picture into a post, when _not_ posting a link also, is to upload a photo to the wall. You can add a message to that, too.

Comment: Yes, true, but if I upload more photos, they are grouped together. I already tested this behaviour. Anywho, this was a requirement from my client.. I'll just have to disappoint him:)

Answer (score 3):

It should be `object_attachment` instead of `object_id`.

Check the document here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

Comment: This is not work properly. The thumbnail is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same thing - it seems like a gross omission from the APIs to leave out something which is what most people do.

The only way around it that I have found is to first create a unique serial-numbered album, and then post the photo to that album:

```
FB.api('ALBUM_ID/photos', 'post', params, function(response) { ... });
```

Where params contains the post message and the url of the photo/picture. But it's such a kludge, creating an album for a single picture! However, that way you don't get subsequently posted pictures grouped together.

There is a more complete code snippet at [How to do simple Facebook status post with text and picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270741/how-to-do-simple-facebook-status-post-with-text-and-picture).

Comment: Create album - is right logic. For example, native Facebook for Android todo: create album with name "MobileUploads", upload photo to this album and create post at feed with this photo.

Answer (score 0):

Use you photo_id after photo upload to get photo info. Photo info includes a set of links to its thumbnails. User one of the thumbnail link to post on the wall by "/me/feed" graph API. See the link to get more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23199781/989896

Answer (score 0):

You should use **/me/photos** without **no_story** parameter. You can add your message to message parameter and it will appear on the user's story board.