# How to do simple Facebook status post with text and picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the JavaScript API. I can do a simple text post with no problem:

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'The text';
FB.api("me/feed", 'post', params, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error)
      alert(response.error.message);
   else
      alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
});
```

Adding a picture with:

```
params['picture'] = "http://mysite.com/link-to-picture";
params['type'] = "photo";
...
```

Posts a link-type status with a garbled link, using the picture as a thumbnail.

If I use "my/photos", it works fine the first time:

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'The text';
params['url'] = "http://mysite.com/link-to-picture";
FB.api("me/photos", 'post', params, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error)
      alert(response.error.message);
   else
      alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
});
```

But then if I do another post I lose the first post item from my feed, and get an album type presentation in the feed with the text from the second post, and both (unrelated) pictures

The only way I have been able to get distinct status posts with their own text and picture is by first creating a serial numbered album, and then posting the picture to that.

```
var aparams = {};
aparams['name'] = "post"+postid;
aparams['message'] = "album for post "+postid;
FB.api("me/albums", 'post', aparams, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error)
  {
     alert("Creating album: "+response.error.message);
  }
  else
  {
     alert('Album ID: ' + response.id);
     var aid = response.id;
     params['url'] = "http://mysite.com/link-to-picture";
     FB.api(aid+"/photos", 'post', params, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error)
           alert("Posting photo: "+response.error.message);
        else
           alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
     });
  }
});
```

That can't be the right way to do it - creating a mass of single picture albums!

I notice that I have by default a 'Timeline Photos' album, so I could get its ID, then upload the picture to that. But then how would I do the FB.api("my/feed" ...) post with just the text and refer to the picture. I can't find anything like that in the documentation.

My requirement seems to me to be very basic. Has anyone been able to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically detects the pictures uploaded in a album at a certain time interval as single post and clubs them. It is also to secure it from spamming through applications.